# как ускорить работу скрипта Задача на codewars, python

Tags: python

Я новичёк, только начал изучение Python. Тут вроде все пересмотрел по моему запросу, не нашел. Точнее нашел, но на С++  :(

Сама задача не сложная по сути, найти пару чисел в списке образующих заданную сумму. (https://www.codewars.com/kata/54d81488b981293527000c8f/train/python)
Подскажите какой иной путь решения этой задачи, я что-то в тупике уже сутки.
Вроде как у меня алгоритм простой:
Находим первую пару, внутри между ними ищем вторую пару, если нет то возвращаем первую.

Все предварительные тесты проходит, упираюсь в ограничение по времени работы.
Сам код (добавлю ниже), изначально был проще, но суть та же. Похоже сам решение найти не смогу, открывать решение пока не хотелось бы, если можно мне бы просто указание на ошибку в логике или подсказку через что попробовать реализовать.

```py
  def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    ind_first, ind_second, val_first, val_second = [], [], [], []
    search_index, x = 0, 0
    for number in ints:
        search_number = (s - number)
        search_index += 1
        search_list = ints[search_index:]
       # print('First for')
        if search_number in search_list:
            ind_first.append(ints.index(number))
            val_first.append(number)
            for x in range(search_index, len(ints)):
         #       print('second for')
                if ints[x] == search_number:
                    ind_second.append(x)
                    val_second.append(search_number)
                    if ind_first[0] < ind_first[-1]:
                        if ind_second[0] > ind_second[-1]:
                            return [val_first[-1], val_second[-1]]
                        return [val_first[0], val_second[0]]
                    else:
                        break
        else:
            continue
    if not val_first:
        return None
 #   return [val_first[0], val_second[0]]
print(sum_pairs([1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8) == [1, 7], "Basic: %s should return [1, 7] for sum = 8" )
print(sum_pairs([1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1], -6) == [0, -6], "Negatives: %s should return [0, -6] for sum = -6" )
print(sum_pairs([20, -13, 40], -7) == None, "No Match: %s should return None for sum = -7" )
print(sum_pairs([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0], 2) == [1, 1], "First Match From Left: %s should return [1, 1] for sum = 2 " )
print(sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10) == [3, 7], "First Match From Left REDUX!: %s should return [3, 7] for sum = 10 " )
print(sum_pairs([4, -2, 3, 3, 4], 8) == [4, 4], "Duplicates: %s should return [4, 4] for sum = 8" )
print(sum_pairs([0, 2, 0], 0) == [0, 0], "Zeroes: %s should return [0, 0] for sum = 0" )
print(sum_pairs([5, 9, 13, -3], 10) == [13, -3], "Subtraction: %s should return [13, -3] for sum = 10" )
```

Comment: Загвоздка по времени работы явно в том, что вы постоянно перебираете весь массив в поисках нужного числа (собственно это делает 'in' и index()). Если сохранять текущий подход то как минимум надо делать только index, если получаем valueError то continue. Так мы от in избавимся. Уже в 2 раза быстрее. Далее перейти полностью на работу с исходным массивом и индексами элементов, убрать срез search_list (та же функция index() получает аргументы откуда начинать поиск), что бы лишний раз ничего не копировать.

Comment: А вот если и этого недостаточно, тогда думать о кардинальном изменении алгоритма. скажем проверяем первый элемент массива, явно проверяем второй - не подошел, перед тем как проверить третий надо бы уже проверить пару 2-3, что бы не искать возможно не существующее число до конца массива, если потом результаты такого поиска будут не нужны. Это либо рекурсия (которая может по лимиту памяти не пройти), либо хитрая игра с массивом как со стеком

Answer (score 0):

Да вроде алгоритм проще некуда, первое, что пришло в голову...
Используем словарь для сохранения самого факта встретившихся значений. Временная сложность поиска в словаре - О(1).
Дальше просто идем по списку и проверяем (по словарю), было ли уже значение, которое необходимо добавить к текущему для получения требуемой суммы. Если было, выводим требуемую пару.
Общая временная сложность всего алгоритма - O(n).

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    cache = {}
    for v in ints:
        if cache.get(s-v, False):
            return [s-v, v]
        cache[v] = True
```

Comment: Друзья, спасибо за отклики, сегодня вечером попробую. 
Проблема действительно в том что функции in и index() перебирают массив. В одном из вариантов кода я уже пытался оптимизировать это тем что вторую пару искал уже между первыми двумя, если такой нет то первая искомая, но это не помогло пройти временной тест. Там предупреждают о списке в 10 000 000 элементов и если первый и последний ообразуют первую пару то такая оптимизация не катит.
Со словарем с ходу не уловил, но попробую разобраться. Была мысль через множества, но там порядок элементов плывет.

Comment: @Lama Если непонятно что делает `if cache.get(s-v, False):`, то можно его заменить на `if s-v in cache:` Просто проверка, что первое число для суммы уже встречалось. Ведь первое число - это сумма минус второе число. А второе число - это текущий элемент списка. Ведь по условию задачи надо вывести пару чисел как только встретится второе число этой пары. Вот от этого условия и пляшем.

Comment: @GrAnd Можно вместо словаря использовать множество `cache = set()` и проверять вхождение во множество `if s-v in chace:`, а для добавления вместо `cache[v] = True` на `cache.add(v)`.

Comment: Блин, снимаю шдяпу :)
У меня 26 строк да еще и "тормознутого" кода, а тут всего 6 ..... охренеть 
Когда видишь решение то просто, а вот чтоб я сам до такого допер ... наверно без шансов. Я почему-то уперся в индексы и все.
Круто! Пойду учиться дальше (пропущу через пошаговый дебаг чтоб проникнуться ) :)
Спасибо.